# Alternative for jQuery's is() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-filter

I was using jQuery's .is() function (the one introduced in 1.6, not the prior version of it) to compare an object, but it unfortunately won't work with jQuery 1.5.2, which is what I am using. I'm wondering if there is some kind of alternative that I can use?

I'm thinking of cloning each object and then comparing it, but this doesn't seem like the best way to do this.

```
                $('#js-show-more-toggle').contents().each(function() {
                if (seen) {
                    $wrapper.append(this);
                } else if ($(this).is($marker)) {
                    // This is what we want to show
                    seen = true;
                }
            }).end().append($wrapper, $more);
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/someprimetime/n4jnr/14/

Comment: The easiest way for stuff like this is usually to look at the jQuery source, see how they implemented it in 1.6, and then copy paste that code into a plugin you can use with 1.5.2

Comment: Or just take a few minutes/hours (depending on the size of the codebase, existence of proper tests, etc.) to switch to recent version of jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this === $marker[0]` to compare the two DOM elements.

Consider upgrading to a recent jQuery version though. Except some minor changes it's usually pretty easy.

Comment: Ah ha. Duh! Thanks. I did that earlier, but I kept it with the jQuery select as `$(this) === $marker[0]`. Thanks :)

Comment: Every `$()` call creates a new object so that can't work. Besides that, in your example you compare the jQuery object with a DOM element.