# JS equivalent of jQuery .is()

Tags: javascript, jquery, equivalent

Is there a pure JS equivalent of jQuery `.is()` on modern browsers?

I know there is the `querySelector` method, but I want to check the node itself, rather than finding child nodes.

Comment: You can view the srouce of jQuery on github or here: [jQuery.fn.is](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.is)

Comment: I can see it, but understand it and rip it out is another question. Also it no doubt includes support for old browsers which I don't want.

Comment: Do you want the nodeName? It's `node.nodeName`?

Comment: @PHPglue no I do not want the node name.

Comment: i dont know if this would this help in your case : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012774/alternative-for-jquerys-is-function

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/3304638/218196

Comment: How about giving the element you're testing a parent then running querySelector from that?

Comment: just use element.matches(strCssSelector); it's in chrome, probably elsewhere too...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like `matchesSelector` is what I want.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.matches

Polyfill is here:

https://gist.github.com/jonathantneal/3062955

```
this.Element && function(ElementPrototype) {
    ElementPrototype.matchesSelector = ElementPrototype.matchesSelector || 
    ElementPrototype.mozMatchesSelector ||
    ElementPrototype.msMatchesSelector ||
    ElementPrototype.oMatchesSelector ||
    ElementPrototype.webkitMatchesSelector ||
    function (selector) {
        var node = this, nodes = (node.parentNode || node.document).querySelectorAll(selector), i = -1;

        while (nodes[++i] && nodes[i] != node);

        return !!nodes[i];
    }
}(Element.prototype);
```

Answer (score 3):

You've already answered your own question, but as per my comment above I looked through the `jQuery.fn.is` function. This isn't a strip from the source, because the function they're using is more generalized so it can be used across multiple other functions, But I've boiled it down to this function:

```
function is(elem, selector){ //elem is an element, selector is an element, an array or elements, or a string selector for `document.querySelectorAll`
    if(selector.nodeType){
        return elem === selector;
    }

    var qa = (typeof(selector) === 'string' ? document.querySelectorAll(selector) : selector),
        length = qa.length,
        returnArr = [];

    while(length--){
        if(qa[length] === elem){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/merrifield69/pen/Iialz?editors=001)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach: Wrap the element you're testing in a parent then run `querySelector` from that

```
function is(el, selector) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = el.outerHTML;
  return div.querySelector(selector);
}
```

I ran one test and it worked:

JS

```
var a = document.querySelector('a');

 if(is(a, '.foo[name=foo]')) {
  console.log('YES');
} else {
  console.log('Nope');
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="foo" name="foo">Meow</a>
```

I am sure this can be done a lot prettier.

Answer (score 0):

According to [youmightnotneedjquery.com](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) depending on your IE compatibility requirement, you can even end up with simpler version:

```
var is = function(element, selector) {
  return (element.matches || element.matchesSelector || element.msMatchesSelector || 
    element.mozMatchesSelector || element.webkitMatchesSelector || 
    element.oMatchesSelector).call(element, selector);
};

is(element, '.my-class');
```

With ES6 this would be:

```
const is = (element, selector) =>
  (element.matches || element.matchesSelector || element.msMatchesSelector || 
    element.mozMatchesSelector || element.webkitMatchesSelector || 
    element.oMatchesSelector).call(element, selector);
};

is(element, '.my-class');
```

Answer (score -2):

Following the concept from @AdamMerrifield it could be useful building the method `is` on any element through the `Element.prototype` chain by doing:

```
Element.prototype.is = function(match) {
    ...
};
```

`Element` is supported by all major browsers, even by IE 8+.

Here is a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/landzup/dL1x70wj/).