# Equivalent of .is() in jquery to native javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to convert my website JavaScript code from jQuery to native JavaScript because I want to learn JavaScript and also remove jQuery in my website.

This is the code im trying to convert

```
 if ($('.product').is('.standalone, .expired')) { //results  }
```

is there an equivalent of this in JavaScript?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS equivalent of jQuery .is()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23644576/js-equivalent-of-jquery-is)

Comment: Did you meant `hasClass()`?

Comment: @ Ionut, yes it can be. how can I target multiple class using native js

Comment: @JohnWick, do you want to add classes or do you want to verify if multiple classes exists on an element? Your question is unclear at least to me

Comment: yes @Ionut I want to verify if multiple classes exists on an element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems in this specific case you want to check if the element contains these two classes, if it is so then you can use `document.querySelectorAll` to get all the matched elements & check `classList.contains` to check if the element have that specific class

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.product').forEach(function(item) {
  if (item.classList.contains('standalone') && item.classList.contains('expired')) {
    item.classList.add('colotText')
  }
})
```

```css
.product {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.colotText {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<div class="product standalone expired">One</div>
<div class="product">Two</div>
<div class="product standalone expired">Three</div>
<div class="product">Four</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. exactly what I'm looking for. God Bless.